# How do I calculate start time for process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, time

How do I calculate the start time for a process in Linux?

I know it's in `/proc/[pid]/sched` but I don't know how to retrieve/convert it.

I have looked various posts here but they're all scripting-related.

Comment: Are you trying to measure how long a program takes to run?

Comment: Do you want how long it takes for a process to get to `_start` or how long it takes to get to `main`?

Comment: @ArthurGreen I am trying to find when the process started in linux using C

Comment: Record the current time in a variable near the start of `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to `fopen` the file `/proc/<pid>/sched` and parse out the contents using `fscanf` or similar.  Yes, it is a lot more trouble than in a scripting language.  That's life with C.

If you want the start time of your own process, then it may be much simpler just to call `gettimeofday` early in your program and save the result in a global variable where other functions can access it.